# Firebase web storage only populates first image

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm querying data in my database and then creating a div with innerHTML. There are two images within the div that I want to populate with var data.

It always populates the first instance of both img tags but will not populate any of the others. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
imgRef.child(PlanUserUID).child("profileP.jpg").getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                      var pp = url;
                      document.getElementById('profileP').style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + pp + '")';

                  }).catch(function(error) {

                  });

                  imgRef.child(PlanUserUID).child("Plans").child(PlanUID).child("1.jpg").getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                      var test = url;
                      document.getElementById('planImg').style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + test + '")';

                  }).catch(function(error) {

                  });

                  var $result = document.createElement("div");
                  $result.className = ("col-md-4");
                  $result.innerHTML = "<div class='countryResults'><img id='profileP' class='profileP' /><img class='planImg' id='planImg' />";
                  $result.onclick = clicked;

                  document.getElementById("results").appendChild($result);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your question. Can you post a screenshot of the result HTML you're getting?

Comment: Hello @RosárioPereiraFernandes here is a link to the screenshot. The issue that I'm creating dynamic html code but the storage calls only add the images to the first dynamic child added to them code.

[link](https://imgur.com/a/hMyST)

Comment: From the code you provided, I can see that you're code is called only once. I don't see any loop that would repeat that for the other 2 instances